# Using Lodash or Underscore JS , how do I obtain a specific key value based on another key value within the same objects array

Tags: javascript

Here is the data I am working with:

```
   myData = 
    [ { sn: '103261101',
        status: 1,
        qty: '189'
      },
      { sn: '106009801',
        status: 1,
        qty: '12'
      }
    ];
```

I am looping thru another array of data, and I want to associate the correct qty to the new array I'm pushing data too. It needs to find the data against the sn.

```
product.push({
  'identifier' :  dataJSON.msg[z].sku,
  'size' : dataJSON.msg[z].size,
  'quantity' : <Here is where I want to do a lodash / underscore find statement> 
});
```

For example 
Easy 1-liner to look at the myData and store the qty based on the matching sn. In this case the dataJSON.msg[z].sku within the loop is the same as the sn value that would be used for the lookup within the myData.

Comment: Maybe this can be done with a pluck?

Comment: would you accept a pure JS solution?

Comment: I'm open to anything. But less lines better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` to get the right item, and then just get the `qty` property of that item.

`_.find(myData, (item) => item.sn === dataJSON.msg[z].sku).qty`

Here's a jsfiddle of it working with lodash: https://jsfiddle.net/vzwst9o4/

The above code is shorthand for this:

```
var matchingItem = _.find(myData, function (item) { 
   item.sn === dataJSON.msg[z].sku
});
matchingItem.qty
```

It should work the same in [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#find) and [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#find) because their `_.find` functions work the same. You can also use [Javascript `find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) as the other answer suggests, but it may be better to use lodash or underscore (especially if you're already using lodash or underscore for other operations) because it ensures cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: are you sure this line is correct? The part where you typed...

.sku).qty ? The syntax does not look correct.

Comment: Yes I believe it is correct. What looks incorrect about it? _.find(...) returns an object, and .qty accesses the qty property of the object returned by _.find.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong. This is for lodash or underscore? sorry for my confusion.

Comment: I was actually thinking lodash when I gave the answer, but it should work for either. I think _.find works the same in both lodash and underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following Ecmascript6 solution with [***Array.prototype.find()***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function:

```
product.push({
  'identifier' :  dataJSON.msg[z].sku,
  'size' : dataJSON.msg[z].size,
  'quantity' : ''  // default value, cause we can't refer to the 'identifier' key while initializing the object via literal 
});

var lastPos = product.length - 1;  // the last `product` position
if (o = myData.find((o) => o.sn === product[lastPos].identifier)) {
    product[lastPos].quantity = o.qty;
};
```